# Importing UTF8 Files with Formatfile in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, bulkinsert

i want to import Textfiles into SQL Server 2014 with the Bulk Insert command. I use Format Files to skip Columns which are not needed.
So this works fine, except for UTF8 Files. Some special characters (ä, ö, ü, ...) are not being imported correctly.

The Solution in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sql-command-in-sql-server-2014-sp2) Article works, but only without using a Format File. I also tried changing the data type in the Formatfile to "SQLNCHAR" which results in this error:

```
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 11, column 1 (col1).
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The 
provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

So how is the UTF8-Codepage used in combination with a format file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out...

Because of UTF8-Encoding, the Collation/Encoding is defined in the bulk insert statement:

```
WITH (CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'Char', ...)
```

the collation in the format file has to be empty in this case and the type has to be "SQLCHAR". For Example, the first line in my format file is this:

```
1   SQLNCHAR    0   50  |   1   column1 ""
```

hope it helps somebody else avoiding hours of searching...